# Create .exe file from asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a School Management web application and sold it to one school.
I don't want to give my code to the school.

How can I run my web application on client machine? Is it possible to create exe file and install that exe file in client machine?  The client wants to run his application in his machine only not on a server.

Answer (score 5):

Better if you host it on the cloud. Compilation would not really protect your .NET code since its MSIL and not machine code.

That said you can compile your ASP.NET code to make it difficult for other people to reuse without significant rework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466(v=vs.100).aspx

You can host your compiled code using a portable IIS e.g : http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/protable-iis-iis-express-75.html

Answer (score 0):

See the deployment process for Asp.Net.

We can deploy ASP.NET Application in  3 different ways

- xCopy Deployment
- Precompiled Deployment
- Web Setup Project

See the refrences here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53075/How-to-deploy-ASP-NET-Web-Application-on-server
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178610(v=vs.80).aspx